# jQuery looping counter

Tags: jquery, loops, counter, jquery-waypoints

I am using a counter to tick off the years between 1850 to 2010 and I'd like it to go up in increments of 10 years. I am trying to trigger the .html swap using divs. For instance, when '.infinite-container1' gets 350pixels from the top, then hypothetically the counter should go from 1850 to 1860 and when '.infinite.container5' gets to 350pixels from the top the counter should change from 1860 to 1870 and so on. However, I must be doing something wrong with my code or math or both because it only reads as 2170 when the first div passes 350px. Help?

```
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i=i+5){
    $('.infinite-container' + i).waypoint(function () {
        document.getElementById("year").innerHTML=(1850+10*i);
    }, {offset: 350});
}
```

Comment: if you are using jquery, why use document.getElementById?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty common scope problem.

The value of `i` when requested by the `waypoint()` call is the value at the end of the loop. To keep the value, you can create new scope who'll hold the `i` on declaration value:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i=i+5){
    (function(i) {
        $('.infinite-container' + i).waypoint(function () {
            document.getElementById("year").innerHTML=(1850+10*i);
        }, {offset: 350});
    })(i);
}
```

I suggest reading this blog post: http://www.2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-variable-scope.html